# Gitlab job failure: Cannot overwrite variable Host because it is read-only or constant

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Hi people of the internet.

Basically I am unable to run even the simplest job and I keep getting the same error no matter what I put in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. See example below:

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
- test

job1:
stage: test
tags:
- testing
script:
- echo "Hello world!"
```

Here is the output ("?" corresponds to intentionally blacked out information):

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.0 (c6bb62f6)
on runner_test ????????
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on LAPTOP-????????...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
WriteError:
Line |
219 | $HOST="[MASKED]"
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot overwrite variable Host because it is read-only or constant.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I know that `$HOST` is a reserved variable in powershell but I don't see the link between the error and the code. It may have something to do with the configuration of the runner on Windows. Has anyone encountered this error on Gitlab before? Or any suggestions on how to debug?

---

Here are the steps that I took to install the runner on Gitlab for Windows (see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html):

1. Create a folder somewhere in the system: `C:\GitLab-Runner`.
2. Download the binary for 64-bit and put it into the folder (see https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe).
3. Run prompt as an administrator
4. Run the following command:

   ```
    cd C:\GitLab-Runner
    gitlab-runner.exe register
   ```
5. Enter your GitLab instance URL (see Gitlab > Settings > CI/CD > Runners > Specific runners)
6. Enter the token to register the runner (see Gitlab > Settings > CI/CD > Runners > Specific runners)
7. Enter a description for the runner: `runner_test` for instance
8. Enter the tags associated with the runner, separated by commas: `testing, windows` for instance
9. Provide the runner executor: `shell`
10. Install GitLab Runner as a service and start it

    ```
    cd C:\GitLab-Runner
    gitlab-runner.exe install
    gitlab-runner.exe start
    ```

---

I also had to install the latest version of pwsh in Windows (see [gitlab-runner: prepare environment failed to start process pwsh in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050125/gitlab-runner-prepare-environment-failed-to-start-process-pwsh-in-windows)):

1. Run prompt as an administrator
2. Install the newer `pwsh.exe`:

   ```
    winget install Microsoft.PowerShell
   ```
3. Restart the runner

   ```
    cd C:\GitLab-Runner
    gitlab-runner.exe restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to my choice of shell for some reason. A Gitlab runner can choose a shell among the following: `bash`, `sh`, `powershell`, `pwsh`, and `cmd` (the last one being deprecated now).

As I stated above I had been using `pwsh`. So, I went after the `config.toml` file inside of the `C:\GitLab-Runner` directory to manually make the change from `pwsh` to `powershell`.

```
...
[[runners]]
  name = "runner_test"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
...
```

I then restarted the runner and got the job to complete properly:

```
cd C:\GitLab-Runner
gitlab-runner restart
```

I still get the error (more like a warning now) but it does not prevent the job from finishing anymore. If anyone has a better answer with a proper explanation I would gladly accept it as the answer to this question.

Note that `pwsh` to `powershell` are both powershell scripts (see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html):

```
powershell  Fully Supported PowerShell script. All commands are executed in PowerShell Desktop context. In GitLab Runner 12.0-13.12, this is the default when registering a new runner.

pwsh        Fully Supported PowerShell script. All commands are executed in PowerShell Core context. In GitLab Runner 14.0 and later, this is the default when registering a new runner.
```